# xampp phpmailer send email - connect err 10060

Tags: php, xampp, phpmailer

I am trying to send email from server which runs locally by xampp. Could you please help me to find possible solution?

I am sure I've used the correct email and password. SMPT port in php.ini and sendMail.ini is also set to port 25.

my php code:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);                             
try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               
    $mail->Username = 'mygmailadress@gmail.com';           
    $mail->Password = 'mypassword';                          

    $mail->Port = 25;
    $mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('mygmailadress@gmail.com', 'Joe User');    

    $mail->isHTML(true);                                 
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

PHP responded with error:

SERVER -> CLIENT: 421 Cannot connect to SMTP server 64.233.166.108 (64.233.166.108:25), connect error 10060

CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost

SERVER -> CLIENT:

SMTP ERROR: EHLO command failed:

SMTP NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connected

SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.

SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.

Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.

Thank you :)

Comment: _"Cannot connect to SMTP server"_ You're likely being firewalled client side or blocked server side.

Comment: Port 587, not 25.

Comment: 25 is open and listening, FWIW. It should at least connect.